# "Require user User1 User2" is not working for User2, only User1

Tags: apache, unix

I am setting up permissions on a site and there are certain sections where I only want 2 users to have permission, User1 and User2. For some reason User1 has access but User2 does not.

According to this link https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html I can include multiple users in the Require user line

My Code looks like this except the paths are actually correct

```
<Directory "/path/to/RestrictedDirectory">
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "Restricted Content"
   AuthUserFile /path/to/AuthUserFile
   Require user User1 User2
</Directory>
```

User1 can access RestrictedDirectory but User2 can't and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer

I had to run `sudo systemctl restart apache2` now User1 and User2 may access